# JavaScript nested addEventListener in callback of another addEventListener is firing immediately

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have this mobile link menu that I want to open with a button and be able to close by all means possible. Either by clicking the same button again, clicking one of the menu links, or anywhere else on the page. Meaning that once the menu is open, every single pixel on the screen is a valid candidate for detecting and closing the menu.

That's why I set up a listener for the menu button to toggle the menu. And once the menu is visible, set up another one-time-listener on the whole document to toggle it hidden again:

```js
document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("box clicked");
    
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('everything clicked');
    }, {once: true})
})
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red"></div>
```

When the first eventlistener detects a click, it runs the callback function. Inside that function, I've set up another onClick listener that fires instantaneously like it's piggybacking off the other click event!

I understand that due to propagation nested listeners will both be activated, but what I'm expecting is that the very first time a click is registered only the "box clicked" will run since once inside the callback function, the event has passed and the second listener needs to wait for the next click event to be able to detect it. But instead, it adds a listener and detects it immediately.

**My expected logs (from sequentially clicking on the box):**

1. - box clicked
2. - box clicked
   - everything clicked
3. - box clicked
4. - box clicked
   - everything clicked
5. - box clicked
6. - box clicked
   - everything clicked

etc...

Comment: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this solution inspired and based on Scott's solution, but with the additional last tweaks to make the solution follow the expected behavior precisely.

```js
let toggleBox = false

document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log("box clicked");
  if (!toggleBox) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  toggleBox = !toggleBox
  
  document.addEventListener('click', handleDocClicked, {once:true});  
});

function handleDocClicked(){
  console.log('everything clicked');
  toggleBox = false
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red">Click me to fire my handler and set up the document handler.</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the box up to have a `click` event as well as the `document`. **But, the box is part of the document**, so when you click the box, the event propagates to the `document` as well. This is because [events propagate](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) and as soon as you click the box, you've set up the document handler and it happens so quickly that the new handler is in place before the initial click event propagates to the document.

If you don't want box clicks to do this, use the [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method in that handler.

**But, you've got another issue with this code. Because you are setting up a document event handler when the box gets clicked, it will set up an additional handler on the document EVERY TIME you click the box.**

**Try it below by clicking the box 3 times and then click outside of the box once.**

```js
document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log("box clicked");
    
  document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('outside of box clicked');
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red">Click me to fire my handler and set up the document handler.</div>
```

To get around this, it's best to set up a variable to keep track of whether the document handler has already been set:

```js
let boxClicked = false;

document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log("box clicked");
  
  // Only set the next handler if it's the first time you've clicked the box
  if(!boxClicked) {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('outside of box clicked');
    });
  }
  
  boxClicked = true;
})
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red">Click me to fire my handler and set up the document handler.</div>
```

Or (and this is more resource intensive), remove the old handler before adding a new one. This technique requires that the callback function be set up as a named function. Your edited question shows you using the `{once:true}` options argument for `addEventLister()`, which solves the problem, but that code essentially does the following, which (as I say) is more resource intensive because constantly adding and removing listeners uses memory.

```js
document.querySelector('#box').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  console.log("box clicked");
  
  // Remove the first handler
  document.removeEventListener("click", handleDocClicked)
  
  // Then set up a new one
  document.addEventListener('click', handleDocClicked);  
});

function handleDocClicked(){
  console.log('outside of box clicked');
}
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red">Click me to fire my handler and set up the document handler.</div>
```

Comment: Yes I understand that once everything is up and running but I'm interested in the very first time the event handlers initiate. Because from the beginning there is only one event handler that get's triggered and in it's callback it adds another eventhandler that gets triggered immediately. Why is that?

Comment: @Zagi Because events "bubble" up to the document level. The first event may have been triggered by one handler being set up, but the event continues to "bubble" upward to the document as well. And, after you've clicked that box, that second handler gets set BEFORE the current event bubbled up to the document, so you get two handlers. This is how event bubbling works.

Comment: @Zagi See my updated answer for more details on your initial question and to show that you've got another issue you may not have been aware of.

Comment: So you're saying that on click, the browser will start capturing events from top down, registering both document and box has been clicked, and storing that information. Then "bubbles" up, calling corresponding event handlers, if there are any. And since the box's handler will add a listener onto the document, once the bubbling reaches the document, it will thereby have a click listener set? OK, I thought that the capturing phase saved only the objects that have click listeners on them already and during "bubbling" just fired their handlers.

Comment: @Zagi Sort of. The capturing phase isn't what is making this happen (you have to pass `true` as an argument to `addEventListener()` for your event to be registered into the capture phase and %99.99 of the time, it's not used), it's the bubbling phase. Capturing simply happens before bubbling. I'm simply saying that at the moment you click the box, the document handler is established and this happens before the actual `click` event is able to bubble up to the `document`, so by the time it does, the document's handler has already been established.

Comment: Alright well I saw a video from Wes Bos explaining that for an event. like `click`, the browser always starts the event process from top, capturing and saving the elements affected all the way down to the target element. Then the bubble phase starts going up the chain of saved elements calling handlers on its way. And the option to "use capture" just means to call the handlers during the capture phase instead of the bubbling phase.

But alright, I understand. Just edit your answer to include the {once: true} in a snippet, and I'll consider the problem solved.

Comment: @Zagi It's true that the browser does do that capture phase first, but there is no "saving" of elements. And, since you are not using capture, the entire discussion of it is irrelevant to your use case, bubbling is all that matters. Also, why do I need to add a `{once:true}` snippet? You are already using that and I do have a snippet that shows just what is actually happening from its use.

Comment: I'm just saying that an accepted answer should be, if possible, based on the original code with addition to the change/solution (stopPropagation) to reach the expected outcome, as well as the reason why (your explanation). 

If we put it like this: there is currently no snippet on this question that will produce the expected outcome. Either I will post an answer, but I'd rather you do it since you've explained everything so well. Thanks

Comment: @Zagi ??? There are 2 solutions posted in my answer that produce the desired results the first of which is the best way, which I mentioned

Comment: Oh sorry, both `capture: true` and `once: true` needs to be used to produce the **expected** logs. Namely, first time box is clicked: "box clicked". All other times box is clicked: "everything clicked", and "box clicked".

Comment: @Zagi I’m not sure why you are hung up on capture. It is rarely, if ever needed, not supported in IE and definitely not needed here.

Comment: It's ultimately because thats how my mobile menu is used. There's always a listener on the menu button, whose callback function is a toggler, toggling the menu visible and hidden. I wanted to implement a feature where once you click outside the menu ,it closes. But I realised since there being no "passive" area on the menu or anywhere else on the page I might as well add an listener on `document` to close it, independent of what action you did. Se my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nermin99/cau4e26d/73/) it should explain everything.

Comment: I know creating and removing an eventlistener so often is not desirable and more performance heavy, it's just that's how I first went about solving the problem and I wanted to see if it was possible, and then (this question) why it first wasn't working.

Comment: @Zagi Yes, but none of that has to do with event capturing. You’ve brought that topic into this and don’t seem to understand that it has nothing to do with your question or the solution.